# How to use a variable in place of column names when doing select in Pyspark/Sparksql

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a variable with column names in it, like below:

VAR=Fullname,Address,DOB

I need to pass this variable in my spark sql instead of column names like below:

```
spark.sql("""
           Select
           VAR
           From mytable
           where 1=1
           #some additional filters
           """)
```

so it is treated as if I was giving the column names explicitly like below:

```
spark.sql("""
           Select
           Fullname
           ,Address
           ,DOB
           From mytable
           where 1=1
           #some additional filters
           """)
```

how can this be implemented using pyspark/sparksql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is code sample in pyspark for same,

```
var = 'Fullname,Address,DOB'

query = "SELECT {} FROM From mytable WHERE 1=1 #additional filters".format(var)

spark.sql(query)
```